# sequelize group by fn count becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My query is as shown below :

```
db.test.findAll({
  group: ['source'],
  attributes: ['source', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'source'), 'count']],
  order: [
    [Sequelize.literal('count'), 'DESC']
  ]
}).then((sources) => {
  sources.forEach((info) => {
    console.log('sorce name :' + info.source + " count : " + info.count);
  })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

So, here what happens is `info.source` name is printed perfectly. But `info.count` is `undefined` even if it is shown in the response ?

Comment: I have not used sequelize.js for a while, but shouldn't it be `Sequelize.col('source')`, instead of just `'source'`: `Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('source'))`?

Comment: @t.niese i even wrote `Sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('source'))` , the result is the same and `count` is still undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequelize is trying to map result to `test` model, use `raw: true` to prevent that...

```
db.test.findAll({
  group: ['source'],
  attributes: ['source', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'source'), 'count']],
  order: [
    [Sequelize.literal('count'), 'DESC']
  ],
  raw: true, // <-- HERE
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this issue myself. Instead of having to use `raw: true`, you can use `instance.get('attribute')`, so in your case

```
sources.forEach((info) => {
  console.log('source name :' + info.source + " count : " + info.get('count');
})
```

You could also do `info.dataValues.count`